# Trying to make a webpage so it stops resizing?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver, html

I'm trying to make a webpage with a lovely `position: fixed` declaration for the header, but if you view it in a browser that is thinner than my roughly 16:9 screen, the protruding logo shows over the top of some text. I don't wnat this. I'd quite like it so that the webpage has something like this *obviously* fake Javascript code.

```
while(1+1=2)
{

if(theWidthOfTheContainer = tooThin) {
    stopMakingTheContainerThinner;
    justMakeAScrollbarAppear.TheBottom;
    }
else {
    carryOnMakingItThinner
 }
}
```

Is there some kind of command for that? Please don't hate on the code, I know it'd never work...

Comment: do you have an example of the problem?

Comment: I do, but as I use image files, it isn't easy to put it up here. Suggestions?

Comment: You can replace images with placehold.it/150x100 where the numbers are width x height. Nice way of showing images in examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `min-width` css rule. It might not work properly in older browsers though, but should give you coverage for most modern ones.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting... And a lot more user-friendly than the Javascript I envisioned. Thanks!!

Comment: You are talking only IE6 and earlier for browser support issues. Not even worth worrying about IMO.